# How are variables scoped when calling the same Play template again?

Tags: java, templates, view, playframework

I'm writing a tag that keeps track of how many time it was called, in order to generate unique ids for its elements:

```
%{
    try {
      coolTagId++;
    } catch (Exception) {
      coolTagId = 0;
    }
}%
<div id='cool-tag-${coolTagId}'></div>

...

$('#cool-tag-${coolTagId}').click(function(){alert("Cool Tag ${coolTagId} clicked")});
```

When I include this tag in a page multiple times, to my surprise, I see that `coolTagId` is 0 every time it's evaluated. Why is this happening?

(I'll be using some sort of UID in the meantime, I just want to understand why the above snippet doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *why* that is but it doesn't surprise me. Play is a stateless framework, so it seems natural that it doesn't share state between two instances of the same tags.

It's interesting, even setting the value beforehand using `#{set coolTagId:0 /}` does not work.

What does work however is setting the value in your tag. Put this at the end of your tag: `#{set coolTagId:coolTagId /}`. This way you manually push the value to the base template.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple matter of scope.

Imagine writing this in pure Java, a tag is effectively calling a method. Everything defined in your tag (i.e. method) is locally scoped to that tag, so it would not exist once the tag has been executed, as it would have left the scope.

The reason for this, is to make sure that anything outside of your tag is not broken or modified by the execution of your tag. Everything is self contained, except for the parameters that you pass in.

Comment: Reminds me that in WebObjects, there is a not-so-simple mechanism for synchronizing variables between components. This behavior is enabled by default and the first step to making your components efficient is to manage synchronization manually, or even better transform them to stateless components.